# How do I group one column in R by values to form two individual boxplots?

Tags: r

For example, let's say I had a column of height like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col = c(70, 80, 74, 50, 59, 55, 65, 30, 55, 80))
```

I want to separate this column into a group that is greater than 55 or less than or equal to 55 and then make two boxplots. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `boxplot(df1$Col ~ df1$Col > 55)`

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` the 'Col' based on the logical `vector` and do the `boxplot`

```
boxplot(split(df1$Col, df1$Col > 55))
```

---

Or using `ggplot2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
  group_by(gr = factor((Col > 55)+1)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=gr,y =Col))+
          geom_boxplot()
```

As @rawr commented, it can be done within `ggplot`

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Col > 55, Col)) + 
                 geom_boxplot()
```

Or if we just need a grouping variable

```
 (df1$Col > 55) + 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col = c(70, 80, 74, 50, 59, 55, 65, 30, 55, 80))
```